# Assigning a tag property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Alright so I'm currently trying to make several UITextFields obtain **"tag"** properties in my code, and her it is:

```
- (IBAction)userDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    _userFirstNameEntry = UserFirstName.text;
    _userLastNameEntry = UserLastName.text;
    _emailEntry = UserEmail.text;
    _userEntry = UserUser.text;
    _userPasswordEntry = UserPassword.text;

    UserFirstName.tag = 1;
    UserLastName.tag = 2;
    UserEmail.tag = 3;
    UserUser.tag = 4;
    UserPassword.tag = 5;

    if(UserFirstName.tag == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserFirstName did end editing");

    }
    else if(UserLastName.tag == 2)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserLastName did end editing");
    }
    else if(UserEmail.tag == 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserEmail did end editing");
    }
    else if(UserUser.tag == 4)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserUser did end editing");
    }
    else if(UserPassword.tag == 5)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserPassword did end editing");
    }

    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I'm using storyboard and I also have the tag properties set inside of the storyboard file using the attributes inspector but currently the statements inside my if logic is not even working..  I'm just simply trying to set the 5 UITextFields to have tag properties, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems.

If you're laying out your text fields in a storyboard, and setting the tags in the storyboard, there's no reason to set the tags again in your `userDoneEditing:` method.

Also, if you want to set tags, you would usually do that in an initialization method (like `viewDidLoad`) instead of in an action method like `userDoneEditing:`.

Also, your code says `(UITextField.tag == 2)`.  But `UITextField` (the class object) doesn't have a `tag` property.  Only instances of `UITextField` have a `tag` property.  I think you meant to say `textField.tag` again in that case.

Also, you appear to have instance variables connected to the text fields (`UserFirstName`, `UserLastName`, and so on).  Did you connect these to the text fields in your storyboard?  Or initialize them in some other way?  If you didn't connect them somehow, then they are nil and trying to set their tags does nothing.

Also, you are referring to a `textField` variable, but that's not an argument or local variable of your method.  Did you mean to use `sender`?

Also, if you have instance variables connected to your text fields, you don't need to use tags at all.  It would be simpler to compare `textField` (or, probably, `sender`) to each of your instance variables in turn:

```
if (sender == UserFirstName) {
    NSLog(@"UserFirstName did end editing");
} else if (sender == UserLastName) {
    NSLog(@"UserLastName did end editing");
} else ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I did make the change of "textField.tag" to "(instance variable).tag", and I do have the IBOutlets connected, the reference variables.  I will say, however, that this is very unnecessary, I should totally be using sender.

Answer (score 0):

What is textField? It looks like you need something like this to assign sender to a text field:

```
- (IBAction)userDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)sender;
    //...
}
```